# How to increment running timer

Tags: c#, .net, timer

In my application I define a timer and set the interval for x seconds.
After that when a 'click' event occurs I want to increment the running timer for y more seconds.

How can I do this?

**The code sample:**

```
private static Timer sTimer = new Timer();
sTimer.Interval = 50000;
```

When the event is invoked I want to do something like that:

```
sTimer.Interval = timeLeftInms + 5000;
```

Comment: So what's wrong with this solution?

Comment: timeLeftInms not exist

Comment: there is no property in timer object that can return time that left.

Comment: You have to track time that left yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create a custom Timer, which inherits from System.Timers.

Have a `private Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();` private member.

On Timer.Start: stopWatch.Start();

On Timer.Tick: stopWatch.Reset();

On

```
Timer.Interval 
          set {
                   _timer.Interval = _timer.Interval - 
                    stopwatch.Elapsed.Miliseconds + value;
              }
```

Comment: good idea, what microsoft didn't done property for that case?

Comment: well, they can't really think of every scenario people want to use the timer, so they got you the basics, and the ability to modify it

Comment: i think the left time is something that need to be ;) very useful

Comment: Very liked your solution, Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

have a timer that updates your system/view/whatever in a regular interval like every 250ms

when your system starts populate a datetime to hold the value when the first event is going to happen ... like DateTime.Now + TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)

update said datetime variable instead of your timer ...

time left is the difference between your variable and DateTime.Now

Comment: that solving the problem but additional object not the best code solution (need always to be maintained) and if i had more than one everyone need to be with its own timespan ...

Comment: What i can do is extention method for timer object and in this case use your solution to add for wxample sTimer.TimeLeft

Comment: if in doubt, store your datetimes in a dictionary and user the corresponding timer as key

Answer (score 0):

Just do

sTimer.Interval += 5000;

inside the click event

Comment: interval is the time that the timer will be runnung in your example if i had the timer run for 10 sec and the main interval was 50 sec after the update you will have only 5 sec for timer ending and i what in my case 45 sec.